# Writing PowerDNS back-end in Lua

Tags: lua, dns

I just *cannot* get this to work. The script answers correctly, and PowerDNS sees it as working, but then the process never gets beyond an acknowledgement of its readiness.

The PowerDNS server gets stuck in read(), and all network connections on port 53 are ignored totally. The server starts a pdns_server process as well as the script itself, and nothing happens. Logging at level 9 is totally and utterly worthless: nothing happens.  Ditto for "pdns monitor" except that the stderr output from the script can be seen.

I've put the script [here](http://pastebin.com/n9McpL17). This is *so* frustrating... what am I missing? Is it the `io.lines()` call? Is it because the input is buffered?

**Update:** I'm using the [documentation](http://downloads.powerdns.com/html/backends-detail.html) to create this. I've also looked at other languages (I know a few) - such as [v6rev](http://hyse.org/v6rev/) (though I don't know Python) and [this example](http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/135/powerdns-custom-dns-backend/) of a backend in Java.

**Update 2** I better mention that this is combined with a `gmysql` backend as well; PowerDNS does allow multiple backends, though I don't know the specifics of it. I did switch the order of the backends in the configuration file, with no changes seen afterwards. Also, MySQL queries *do* work. Without the `pipe` backend, the MySQL backend handles things just fine.

Comment: So not to ask an obvious question, but have you removed all of the stderr outputs to see if it's the console blocking on a write?

Comment: No - but the copious io.stderr:write calls are new; I had zero before, and adding these calls changed nothing. So I doubt that that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one has any tips, so... this is what I found out. It is indeed related to buffering - or at least, that's what it looks like. The code originally had lines like this:

```
print("OK\tPowerDNS backend ok")
```

These lines were where the problem was; replacing them with this sequence worked:

```
print("OK\tPowerDNS backend ok")
io.flush()
```

However - replacing them with the following sequence did *not* work:

```
io.write("OK\tPowerDNS backend ok")
io.flush()
```

Presumably this is because of some difference between `print()` and `io.write()`. Looking for details on Lua unbuffered I/O turned up nothing. It may be that I should use `io.stdout.write()` instead of `io.write()`.

By accident, I ran across [this posting](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-10/msg00369.html) to the Lua-Users mailing list which mentions the [`setvbuf`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-file%3asetvbuf) function. However, the `setvbuf` function appears to be new as of Lua 5.1, so it is not available in Lua 5.0.